Use container query for standard css properties
I tried to get the container style query working, but found some oddities.
Consider the following code:
html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    ...
  </div>
</div>

CSS
.parent {
  --test-var: red;
  background-color: grey;
}

@container style(background-color: grey)
/* @container style(--test-var: red) */
{
  .child {
    background-color:red;
  }  
}


The above css rule does not apply the 'child-style' eventhough this should work following the MDN documentation about this feature.
Using the query on custom properties (i.e. by using the commented css-query), things work as expected/documented (tested with chrome version 128.0.6613.138, among other things).
Maybe this feature is not ready yet to be used in this way.
But if I missed something, I would love to know.
Added a jsfiddle if someone wants to try this out.

it's not ready, you can test with only style(background-color) and it won't work as well

style properties visual ones like background-color, might not have uniform support in container queries across all browsers. this feature is still being developed/fine-tuned
potential workarounds:

use custom properties to apply styles
@container style(--test-var: red) {
    .child {
      background-color: red; 
}}


for more complicated style adjustments, you can put in place a temporary JavaScript solution as a fallback:
const parent = document.querySelector('.parent');
const child = document.querySelector('.child');

const parentBackgroundColor = window.getComputedStyle(parent).backgroundColor;
if (parentBackgroundColor === 'rgb(128, 128, 128)') {
  child.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}


or use the above suggested container-type method with width or size based queries.


